# How access class/Object inside function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here I want to get and set the carbrand with in the function, but it throws error as:

```
myscript.js:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Cars' before initialization
at getCarsInfo (myscript.js:79)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ClassWithGetterAndSetter.html:9)**
```

```
class Cars{
    constructor(brand)
    {
        this.carBrand=brand;
    }
    get carBrandName()
    {
        return this.carBrand;
    }
    set carBrandName(newCarName)
    {
        this.carBrand=newCarName;
    }
}


function getCarsInfo()
{
   mycar=new Cars("Tata");
    console.log("Hi ");
    mycar.carBrandName("abc");
   mycar.carBrandName(document.getElementById("getCarName").value);
   console.log(mycar.carBrand)
   document.getElementById("carDetails").innerHTML=mycar.carBrand;
}
```

Comment: You'd get this kind of error if `class Cars ...` came ***after*** `function getCarsInfo`… Is this really your exact code?

Comment: @deceze - The order of the code above will also have the problem if `getCarsInfo` is *called* from above what's shown. (`getCarsInfo` is hoisted, `Cars` is only half-hoisted -- the declaration, but not the initialization.)

Comment: your function should look like `function myFunction() {
  return this.carBrand;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the code you've shown will have that error depends on when you call `getCarsInfo`. If you have

```
getCarsInfo();

class Cars {
    // ...
}

function getCarsInfo() {
    // ...
}
```

you'll get that error, because `Cars` isn't given its value until it's reached in the step-by-step execution of the code (until then it's in the Temporal Dead Zone).

But if you do:

```
class Cars {
    // ...
}

getCarsInfo();

function getCarsInfo() {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
class Cars {
    // ...
}

function getCarsInfo() {
    // ...
}

getCarsInfo();
```

or

```
function getCarsInfo() {
    // ...
}

class Cars {
    // ...
}

getCarsInfo();
```

it will work, because `Cars` is initialized by the time `getCarsInfo` tries to use it.

---

Side note: You use accessor properties like your `carBrandName` as *properties*, not as methods:

```
myCar.carBrandName = "...";
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into `const`, `let`, `class`, and the Temporal Dead Zone in some detail in Chapter 2 of my new book (see my profile for details).